# Header with Chapter and section on page of chapter begin

Tags: header-footer

How can I display the section in the header of the page that starts a chapter?

On following pages the chapter and the sections are displayed but not on the page where the chapter starts.

If there is no good reason to not display the section as well, I would like it to be displayed.

Also. The chapter is not displayed on the 3rd page. Instead of the chapter and the section, "List of listings" is displayed.

```
    \documentclass[
   final,
   12pt,
   a4paper,
   oneside
]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% to alighn the TOC numbers on the right
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[headheight=30pt,
            a4paper,
            left=42mm,
            right=29mm,
            top=32mm,
            bottom=38mm
]{geometry}  % or %\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
%% IN NEW END

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    %\pagestyle{fancy}
    %\pagestyle{fancyplain}
    %\fancyhead{}
    %\fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
        \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
        \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
        \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}}
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {\@mkboth{\mbox{}}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%# IN NEW END

\frontmatter
%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\pagenumbering{Roman}
%% OUT NEW BEGIN

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\small\thepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code listing}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\mainmatter

%% IN NEW BEGIN
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
%% IN NEW END

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyhead{}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\lhead{}
%\rhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{Some section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{Some section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to write those lot of dummy text. Just use `lipsum` package and write `\lipsum[1]` for example.

Comment: The basic idea for `fancyhdr` is to do: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{<put your definitions here; i.e., make them match your other definitions>}`. This redefines the 'plain' style to match your 'fancy' style.  In general, however, a page that starts a new chapter doesn't need a "fancy" header.

Comment: It is the norm that a section title is not displayed on the first page of a chapter, since it aims at giving this information when it is not apparent. By definition, if a section begins on  first page, it is apparent from the body of text, so it would be a redundant information.

Comment: Oh, thanks to @bernard's formatting, I see the problem: `\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}`.  This is manually overriding your earlier definitions.  Comment it out.

Comment: I have a one sided layout and would like to have both lines in the header fills with chapter and section all the time, also at the beginning of a chapter.

Comment: The thing is, what if the introduction to the chapter is longer and *no* section starts on the same page. There is a good reason why the standard layout is consistent for quite a few years. Usually the page where a chapter is `plain` because nobody needs a header if the title of the chapter is directly below in huge letters. Please think about it.

Comment: If the introduction to the chapter is longer and no section starts on the same page. Then it should look like it is right now. Then section shall be empty.

Comment: Nobody needs a header if the title of the chapter is directly below in huge letters. Sure, but I need to find a section by looking at the header only. If it is not listed I have to look at other indicators like previous sections, page numbers etc. But if I could write the section name to where the space is right now, I (the reader) would find it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the line `\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}`.

A mark command sets three variables: `\topmark` (last mark of the previous page), `firstmark` (first mark on the current page) and `\botmark` (last mark on the current page). `\rightmark` uses the `\firstmark` set by `\markright` or the second argument of `\markboth`. On a chapter page the first call of `\markboth` is done by `\chapter`, normally with an empty second argument to reset the header entry.

If it is alright to use the last section occurring on the chapter page you could define a command `\rightbotmark` using `\botmark` instead `\firstmark`

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
```

and then

```
\fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightbotmark}
```

at pagestyle `plain` and maybe also at pagestyle `fancy`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
   final,
   12pt,
   a4paper,
   oneside
]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% to alighn the TOC numbers on the right
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[headheight=30pt,
            a4paper,
            left=42mm,
            right=29mm,
            top=32mm,
            bottom=38mm
]{geometry}  % or %\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
%% IN NEW END

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    %\pagestyle{fancy}
    %\pagestyle{fancyplain}
    %\fancyhead{}
    %\fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
        \fancyhead[R]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightbotmark}
        \fancyfoot[L]{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
        \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}}
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
        \hrule height 1.9pt width\headwidth
        \vspace{1.6pt}%
        \hrule height 0.9pt width\headwidth
    }}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {\@mkboth{\mbox{}}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

%%# IN NEW BEGIN
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%# IN NEW END

\frontmatter
%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\pagenumbering{Roman}
%% OUT NEW BEGIN

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\small\thepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code listing}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}
%\rhead{\small{List of Listings}}% <- remove this
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\mainmatter

%% IN NEW BEGIN
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
%% IN NEW END

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing

%% OUT NEW BEGIN
%\fancyhead{}
%\pagestyle{plain}
%\lhead{}
%\rhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark\\\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
%% OUT NEW END

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```